# Trying to save PHP $_POST variable into javascript but it does not work

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to save the `PHP array` and `$_POST` value in to javascript variable but it does not work.

This is how i am doing it.

```
<html>
 <script>
   var username = <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>
   var password = <?php echo $_POST['password']; ?>
   //abc(username, password);
   document.write(username+' '+password);// does not work
</script>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i achieve this?

If i pass a hard coded variable to JavaScript function, that works only. Let me show you how.

```
<script>
function func(v1, v2){
   document.write(v1+' '+v2);// does not work 
}
</script>
<?php
$a = 25;
$b = 30; 
echo '<script>func('.$a.','.$b.');</script>'

?>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? You'll need to be more clear about the problem and what isn't working.

Comment: added some details to my question. Please check out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing your variables `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` are `foo` and `bar` respectively, your JavaScript code is being generated probably like this:

```
var username = foo
var password = bar
```

You need to add quotes around your values to JavaScript parse them as strings too, otherwise it will think you are assigning `foo` and `bar` variables to them.

Also, you should use `addslashes` to escape possible `"`characters in your string and prevent it from breaking your JavaScript code.

```
var username = "<?php echo addslashes($_POST['username']); ?>"
var password = "<?php echo addslashes($_POST['password']); ?>"
```

Comment: Don't forget the ending semicolons.

Comment: Semicolons in JavaScript are optional.

Comment: Thanks @ Guilherme Sehn, it worked. It was not working without semi columns. I added the semicolon and then terminator at the end and it worked.

Comment: Yes, however it's a best practice.

Comment: Clear and concise. `+1`

Comment: There's a lot of FUD about the JavaScript automatic semicolons question, I don't think that appending them is really a best practice, but a matter of preference. I suggest you to take a read at this article: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes:

```
var username = "<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>"
```

Otherwise JavaScript will interpret `$_POST[]` value as an undefined variable.